# How to iterate all keys except one in handlebars?

Tags: html, handlebars.js

I need to iterate each element except one.

```
<ul>
  {{#each [1,2,3,4,5] skip=3}}
    <li>{{@key}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
===> 
iterated keys [1,2,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do all this inside handlebars. Then use an `{{#if }}` clause to filter out your element.

But I think the cleaner way is to inject clean data into your templates. So my take is that you should filter the array with JavaScript before passing it inside your template.